# non-Hamilton path elimination in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, hamiltonian-cycle

Assume that we have a random graph. How do you remove or add edges in the minimum number of steps such that every edge in the resulting graph would be in a Hamilton path?

I would really appreciate if someone can share any ideas.

Comment: homework question? Please tag it!

Comment: it is not a homework. it is a research question.

Comment: Should I tag it research then? I don't think you have the rights.

Comment: I'm new to this system, please do the necessary changes to the post.

Comment: I assume you don't want the easy answer? Generate all graphs on V' = |V| vertices, save the ones which have all vertices on a Hamiltonian path, and keep the one(s) which can be turned into the original in the fewest steps.

Comment: Ok, this solution has exponential order time. I'm looking for a linear time algorithm or even a much more better heuristic.

Comment: Linear time is going to be a lower-bound for any meaningful algorithm, since any meaningful algorithm needs to at least check that all vertices are on the Hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 0):

There's an algorithm to find Hamilton paths quickly in certain random graphs due to [Angluin–Valiant](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=803393). Perhaps you could run it repeatedly for each edge in the graph to extend that edge to a Hamilton path, adding edges when that fails.